# javascript/jQuery function with location.search and click() not firing in IE7 - works elsewhere

Tags: jquery, function, click

Inside my `$(document).ready` I have a function that looks at the url and searches for a variable. If the variable exists the function will fire a fancy box with a video.

The function works in everything except IE7. What am I missing that would cause the break?

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".video").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});

$(function(){
  if(location.search == "?video=true"){
    $('.video').click();
  }
});
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help you con provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(location.search == "?video=true")
```

try replacing it with

```
var url = window.location;
if(url.indexOf("?video=true") >= 0)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the problem in IE7.